# moment.js : list operations functionalities?

Tags: javascript, list, sorting, underscore.js, momentjs

I have used with some satisfaction the library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

I wonder if there is any library that extends what *moment.js* provides with
list operations functionalities, like `uniq`, `sort` and such.

I am especially concerned with sorting operations of *moment* objects. Maybe I can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org)'s `_.sortBy` passing an iterator that returns a unix timestamp of the current *moment* object?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why would a date library be concerned with sorting? JavaScript arrays have a `.sort` method already since version 1, and unique is a 1 line `.filter` call. Also, please phrase your question more clearly and make it a question about how to accomplish something specific and not a library request which is forbidden in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : I did not request a library, I asked for information about the possible existence of a library, which is different. Is this also forbidden is stackoverflow? Moreover, with my question I would like to see if there are any elegant ways to solve my problem.

Comment: Which is why I suggested an edit rather than downvoting or close voting :) Also yes, "library existence" is like library recommendation and is forbidden.